# Why can't I access builtins if I use a custom dict as a function's globals?

Tags: python, function, global, cpython

I have a `dict` subclass like this:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return globals()[name]
```

This class can be used with [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) and [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) without issues:

```
>>> eval('bytearray', MyDict())
<class 'bytearray'>
>>> exec('print(bytearray)', MyDict())
<class 'bytearray'>
```

But if I instantiate a function object with the [`types.FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType) constructor, the function can't access any builtins:

```
import types

func = lambda: bytearray
func_copy = types.FunctionType(func.__code__,
                              MyDict(),
                              func.__name__,
                              func.__defaults__,
                              func.__closure__)

print(func_copy())
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "untitled.py", line 16, in <module>
#     print(func_copy())
#   File "untitled.py", line 8, in <lambda>
#     func = lambda: bytearray
# NameError: name 'bytearray' is not defined
```

Replacing `MyDict()` with `globals()` or `dict(globals())` or event `{'__builtins__': __builtins__}` makes the code print `<class 'bytearray'>` as expected.

I don't understand where this exception is coming from. Can anyone explain this behavior? Why does it work with `eval` but not with a function object?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but what seems to be happening is that CPython ignores the custom `__getitem__` when it accesses the builtins. It seems to treat `MyDict` like a normal (not subclassed) dict. If the `'__builtins__'` key is actually present in the dict, then everything works correctly:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return globals()[name]


import types

globs = MyDict()
globs['__builtins__'] = __builtins__

func = lambda: bytearray
func_copy = types.FunctionType(func.__code__,
                              globs,
                              func.__name__,
                              func.__defaults__,
                              func.__closure__)

print(func_copy())
# output: <class 'bytearray'>
```

The question remains why this only happens with `FunctionType`, and not with `eval` and `exec`.