# Eval() with custom dict doesn't work in CPython

Tags: python, cpython

I'm trying to run some expressions using a custom dict as globals.

```
class Namespace(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == "y":
            return 10
        else:
            return super(Namespace, self).__getitem__(key)

def run_with_dict(d):
    print(eval("x + y", d))
    print(eval("[ (p * y) for p in ['foo', 'bar'] ]", d))
    print(eval("{ p: (p * y) for p in ['foo', 'bar'] }", d))

custom = Namespace()
custom["x"] = 2
regular = {"x": 2, "y": 10}

run_with_dict(regular)
run_with_dict(custom)
```

When running it in CPython 2.7, it fails only on the map comprehension:

```
12
['foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo', 'barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar']
{'foo': 'foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo', 'bar': 'barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar'}
12
['foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo', 'barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 22, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in run_with_dict
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
NameError: global name 'y' is not defined
```

But when it's run with PyPy 2.7, it works fine. It also works fine in any Python 3.

What implementation difference could explain that? Is this a bug in CPython 2.7 or is it undefined behavior? Is there anything I could do to make it work in both implementations?

Comment: I realize that this is toy demonstration code, but is there any reason you couldn't just add `y` as an item to the dict in the initialization?

Comment: Some variables might be loaded dynamically from disk and it's not know upfront which ones are going to be used in a given eval.

Answer (score 2):

CPython often takes shortcuts. The dict comprehension in CPython 2.7 expects the dict to be *exactly* a `dict` and not a subclass thereof. It doesn't bother calling your overridden `__getitem__` method; it goes straight for `dict.__getitem__` which of course can't see an entry with the name `y`.

I'm not really sure if this is undefined behavior or not, but the fact that's been changed in python 3 would imply that it was a bug.

Comment: If anyone's interested, [a similar thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50604799/1222951) happens you pass a subclassed dict to the `FunctionType` constructor.

Comment: This cannot be right, because the first two statements work as expected (and do in fact call the overridden `__getitem__`). As noted in the question, it's only the dict comprehension that fails.

Comment: @ekhumoro I don't follow your logic there. There's evidently some subtle difference between dict comprehensions and the other tested expressions. Why can't that subtle difference be the way dicts are treated?

Comment: @ekhumoro The first statement executes in the module scope (of eval), in python 2 the second also executes in the module scope ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198906/list-comprehension-rebinds-names-even-after-scope-of-comprehension-is-this-righ)). The dict comprehension creates a new scope in 2 and 3. It would seem the new scope (in python 2) short circuits the variable lookup and directly uses `dict.__getitem__`. This could be checked of course making making the subclass print out when `__getitem__` is invoked.

Comment: @ekhumoro Ah, I guess I was a bit unclear in my answer... I'll rephrase it a little.